# Heap Sort Space Complexity

Tags: algorithm, sorting, heapsort, space-complexity

I was just reading through Skiena's Algorithm Design Manual book, in particular the section on Heap Sort. He states that

> It is an in-place sort, meaning it uses no extra memory over the array containing the elements to be sorted

the algorithm in the book looks like this:

```
heapsort(item_type s[], int n) 
{
  int i;
  priority_queue q;

  make_heap(&q, s, n);

  for (i=0; i<n; i++) 
    s[i] = extract_min(&q);
}
```

To me, it looks like in addition to the input array `s` of items, we're creating a heap data structure in the `priority_queue` variable. Doesn't this mean that the required space complexity is O(n) and requires approximately double the memory, not "no extra memory"?

Comment: Hopefully (and traditionally), the heap is established in the array to sort.

Comment: @greybeard I'm not sure I follow what you're saying. If you are given an unsorted array, how can you transform it (in place) into a heap?

Comment: (You make me wonder about the presentation in Skiena's book.) In-place transformation of an array in arbitrary order to an _implicit_ heap (the relation ancestor <-> descendant is defined by array index) is just an in-place permutation, relevant operation names are `heapify` and `sift`. Beyond the basics, there is [Wegener](http://puma.uni-kassel.de/author/Wegener/heapsort) to ask which keys to compare, and [smooth sort](http://www.keithschwarz.com/smoothsort/) for a variation ebarrasingly underrepresented, considering its ability of fully exploiting preexisting order.

Comment: See http://blog.mischel.com/2013/09/30/a-simple-heap-of-integers/ for a description of and sample code for heap-ordering an array in place.

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of heapsort that you've described above sure doesn't look like it works in constant space for precisely the reason that you're worried about.

However, that doesn't mean that it's not *possible* to implement heapsort in O(1) auxiliary space. Typically, an implementation of heapsort would reorder the elements in the array to implicitly store a binary max-heap. One nifty detail about max-heaps is that the way to dequeue from a max-heap is to swap the root node (the first array element) with the rightmost leaf (the last element in the array that's a part of the heap) and to then bubble that element downward. This means that you can repeatedly dequeue from the max-heap by swapping the first array element with the rightmost slot in the array that hasn't been filled in, then bubbling the swapped element into place. That requires only O(1) auxiliary storage space and is the typical way that heapsort is implemented.

If you're curious, I have [my own implementation of heapsort](http://keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=heapsort) on my personal site, which shows off how to do this.